# AesGcm could not be found VS 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, password-encryption, aes-gcm

In C#, I am unable to use AesGcm, I have used 'using System.Security.Cryptography'. I have installed the System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms package with NuGet, but it is not found when I use 'using System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms'.

I am trying to create an enc_password hash for use on Instagram. My .NET Framework version is 4.8.

Comment: Please share your actual [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reproducing the issue and exact error text.

Comment: The [AesGcm class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm?view=netcore-3.0) doesn't exist in .Net Framework 4.8, and seems to have been introduced in .Net Core 3.0 / .Net Standard 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

I also introduced the System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms package in visual studio 2022, and it is normal to use "using System.Security.Cryptography" and "using System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms". But my .NET Framework version is 6.0. You can change to 6.0 and try to see if it works.